# Tar subdirectories separately

Tags: tar

I need to tar a bunch of files, actually ~60 Millions. They are ordered in year/month/day directories. Every day has ~700 files. Is there a "neat" way of taring first the daily directories then put them into monthly tared dirs and finally tar them to yearly directories?
Of course I can try and write a script to do that, but I thought perhaps there is something "out there" or even an inbuilt function that I can use for this task.

Comment: If this is for backup purposes, you could take a look at "rsnapshot". It will copy the files themselves, and through the clever use of links will create daily, monthly and yearly directories. 
Otherwise you will likely need a combination of "find ... | xargs tar" commands.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Actually it is not a backup purpose rather a 'one time delivery' of data.

Answer (score 0):

ok, not nice to answer your own question, nevertheless here is what I did just using the command line:

```
for m in /mypath/<year>/*;do for d in ${m}/*;do tar -cf <year>`basename $m``basename $d`.tar $d;done;done
```

as result I get daily tar files in the form: yyyymmdd.tar

To then tar them to monthly or yearly tar files is then not so difficult.

Any other, more elegant solutions are always welcome.